# NodeJS is reading the same file blocking?

Tags: node.js, filesystems

We have a backend expressjs server that will read off of the disk for many files whenever a front-end client connects.

At the OS level, are these reads blocking?

I.E., if two people connect at the same time, will whoever gets scheduled second have to wait to read the file until the first person who is currently reading it finishes?

We are just using `fs.readFile` to read files.

EDIT: I'm implementing caching anyway (it's a legacy codebase, don't hate me), I'm just curious if these reads are blocking and this might improve response time from not having to wait until the file is free to read.

Comment: If the file(s) never changes, can you read it once and keep it in process memory? If the file does change arbitrarily, then I don't see what better you can do than re-read it. What OS are you running?

Comment: @ggorlen I added an edit - I inherited this codebase and am going to implement some caching anyway, but was just curious if caching would also improve response time since we would be reading from non-blocking process memory instead of (potentially) blocking filesystem memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fs.readFile()` is not blocking for nodejs.  It's a non-blocking, asynchronous operation. While one `fs.readFile()` operation is in progress, other nodejs code can run.

If two `fs.readFile()` calls are in operation at the same time, they will both proceed in parallel.

Nodejs itself uses a native OS thread pool with a default size of 4 for file operations so it will support up to 4 file operations in parallel.  Beyond 4, it queues the next operation so when one of the 4 finishes, then the next one in line will start to execute.

Within the OS, it will time slice these different threads to achieve parallel operation.  But, at the disk controller itself for a spinning drive, only one particular read operation can be occurring at once because the disk head can only be on one track at a given time.  So, the underlying read operations reading from different parts of a spinning disk will eventually be serialized at the disk controller as it moves the disk head to read from a given track.

But, if two separate reads are trying to read from the same file, the OS will typically cache that info so the 2nd read won't have to read from the disk again, it will just get the data from an OS cache.

> I inherited this codebase and am going to implement some caching anyway, but was just curious if caching would also improve response time since we would be reading from non-blocking process memory instead of (potentially) blocking filesystem memory.

OS file caching is heavily, heavily optimized (it's a problem operating systems have spent decades working on).  Implementing my own level of caching on top of the OS isn't where I would think you'd find the highest bang for the buck for improving performance.  While there may be a temporary lock used in the OS file cache, that lock would only exist for the duration of a memory copy from cache to target read location which is really, really short.  Probably not something anything would notice.  And, that temporary lock is not blocking nodejs at all.